# How to change file created comment date format in Intellij Idea-2017.2.5?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

*When i create a java file in Intellij Idea.*

> **My desire date format is:** (dd/mm/yy)
>
> **but my output format:** (mm/dd/yy)

[image]

---

**I used this code in Idea ->File-> Setting -> Editor -> File and code Template -> file header**

- @created ${DATE}
- @project  ${PROJECT_NAME}
- @author ${USER}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: * @created ${DAY}/${MONTH}/${YEAR}

Answer (score 5):

For me the following works: `${DAY}/${MONTH}/${YEAR}`

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**

*Idea ->File-> Setting -> Editor -> File and code Template -> File Header*

**Step-2**

- @created ${DAY}/${MONTH}/${YEAR}
- @project  ${PROJECT_NAME}
- @author ${USER} 
  *

**Step-3**

*click apply & ok*

**Step-4**

*Now Create a File & check it.*